# activate bash with AIX

Tags: bash, aix

I am working with AIX and logged in with a user that is not able to autocomplete directory paths and filenames. First I have to commit `bash`in putty then I can use tabulator-key to autocomplete directory paths.

What do I have to do that I do not need to commit `bash` command? Maybe I have to set an entry to a special file? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to change users, you could change your default shell to bash using smitty for example.

Otherwise just put an `exec bash` in your ~/.profile at the end and your shell will be automatically switched to bash.

Answer (score 0):

Just did this on AIX 7.1.1.0 ! The command is:

```
chsh <username> /bin/bash
```

followed by a restart of the SSH session.

Done.